# Parse html table using LINQ and HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

I want to parse date, link text and link href from **table class='nice'** on web page http://cslh.cz/delegace.html?id_season=2013

I have created object **DelegationLink**

```
public class DelegationLink
{
   public string date { get; set; }
   public string link { get; set; }
   public string anchor { get; set; }
}
```

and used it with LINQ to create **List of DelegationLink**

```
var parsedValues =
from table in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='nice']")
from date in table.SelectNodes("tr//td")
from link in table.SelectNodes("tr//td//a")
   .Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
select new DelegationLink
{
   date = date.InnerText,
   link = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
   anchortext = link.InnerText,
};
return parsedValues.ToList();
```

which takes date column ony by one and combine it with link column in every row, but i just want to simply take every row in table and get date, href and hreftext from that row.
I am new to LINQ and i used google for a 4 hours without any effect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's rather easy, you just have to select the `tr`'s in the `SelectNodes` function calls and adjust your code a bit.
Something like this.

```
var parsedValues = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='nice']/tr").Skip(1)
.Select(r =>
      {
        var linkNode = r.SelectSingleNode(".//a");
        return new DelegationLink()
                  {
                    date = r.SelectSingleNode(".//td").InnerText,
                    link = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("href",""),
                    anchor = linkNode.InnerText,
                  };
      }
);
return parsedValues.ToList();
```